# I want to act the label as hyperlink

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using **antDesign** and **reactjs**

```
 <Form.Item name="City" label="City">
            <Input  maxLength="100" size="small" disabled={true} />
        </Form.Item>
```

I want the label `City` as a hyper link.

https://ant.design/components/anchor/

Using the `<Link>` how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this

```js
<Form.Item name="City" label={<a href="Link_here">City</a>}>
    <Input  maxLength="100" size="small" disabled={true} />
</Form.Item>
```